# Getting data outside of a list in python

Tags: python

I have list with one item in it, then I try to dismantle, & rebuild it.
Not really sure if it is the 'right' way, but for now it will do.
I tried using replace \ substitute, other means of manipulating the list, but it didn't go too far, so this is what I came up with:

This is the list I get :   alias_account = ['account-12345']
I then use this code to remove the [' in the front , and '] from the back.

```
        NAME = ('%s' % alias_account).split(',')
        for x in NAME:
            key = x.split("-")[0]
            value = x.split("-")[1]
            alias_account = value[:-2]
            alias_account1 = key[2:]
            alias_account = ('%s-%s') % (alias_account1, alias_account)
```

This works beautifully when running `print alias_account`.
The problem starts when I have a list that have ['acc-ount-12345'] or ['account']

So my question is, how to include all of the possibilities?
Should I use try\except with other split options? 
or is there more fancy split options ?

Comment: what is your expected result? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: What's wrong with `alias_account[0]`?

Comment: yep, silly me.. you are correct @quamrana. I'm used to deal with enormous lists, but forget to treat this short list, well, emm, as a list. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access a single list element, you can index its position in square brackets:

```
alias_account[0]
```

To hide the quotes marking the result as a string, you can use `print()`:

```
print(alias_account[0])
```

Comment: Amazing, I was overthinking this issue, and forgot to look at the simple solution. thank you.